# Write to specific columns in a csv file

Tags: python, json, csv

I've a script that gets data in a json format through an API. I need to write headers to the file, then append with some of the json data.

```
import requests, csv, json


def test(limit="", api_token=""):
    url_rack = "url"
    api_token = "Token " + api_token
    headers = {'Authorization': api_token}
    params = {'limit': limit}

    session = requests.Session()
    json_data = session.get(url_rack, headers=headers, params=params)

    with open('my_file.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                                quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        filewriter.writerow(['Header1', 'Header2'])


    json_data = json_data.json()['results']
    for i in json_data:
        bunit = i['tenant']
        open(csvfile)
        if not bunit:
            print 'Placeholder'
        else:
            bunit = i['tenant']['name']
            print bunit


    for i in json_data:
        owner = i['tenant']
        if not owner:
            print 'Placeholder Owner'
        else:
            owner = i['tenant']['name']

            print owner



def main():
    api_token = "mytoken"
    test(api_token=api_token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to write the data taken from `for i in tenants:` in the column under Header1, and the data from `for i in owners` under Header2. I have two trivial problems. When I tried to open the csv file inside the for loop I got the error `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found`. I got that the file is open so I can't reopen it, but don't want to create it in the loop as that would rewrite the file each iteration?

Secondly `filewriter.writerow` obviously writes in rows, but I need to write the data in each column under the header. I printed it out to test that I can actually call the api and get the data but can't work out how to append it under Header1 and Header2.

EDIT
My data that prints:

```
Placeholder tenant
Placeholder tenant
Tenant1
Placeholder tenant
Placeholder tenant
Placeholder tenant
Placeholder tenant
Tenant2
Placeholder tenant
Tenant3
Tenant4
```

and

```
Placeholder Owner
Placeholder Owner
Owner1
Placeholder Owner
Placeholder Owner
Placeholder Owner
Placeholder Owner
Owner2
Placeholder Owner
Owner3
Owner4
```

Comment: Are you allowed to provide some sample session data and some sample output? If so, please add those snippets to your question. In addition, `tenants` and `owners` seem to contain same data since both are assigned to `json_data.json()['results']` and to following loops are identical.

Comment: @albert I've edited to add the console output that I'm trying to get in under Header1 and Header2, and you're spot on I see now that I was calling the json results twice, changed to only call it once

Comment: How does your `json_data` look like? I am assuming that you want to save that data as csv-file. Is that correct?

Comment: @albert I'm not saving that json data to a local file, just accessing it through the api and loading it to json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Just needed to write each to a list

```
json_data = prefixes_response.json()['results']
    tenant = []
    for i in json_data:
        bunit = i['tenant']
        if not bunit:
            tenant.append('Placeholder tenant')
        else:
            bunit = i['tenant']['name']
            tenant.append(bunit)
```

and zip both lists and write

```
rows = zip(Header1, Header2)
for row in rows:
     filewriter.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to rewrite your code like this:

```
...

with open('my_file.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    filewriter.writerow(['Header1', 'Header2'])


    json_data = json_data.json()['results']
    for i in json_data:
        bunit = i['tenant']

        if not bunit:
            print 'Placeholder'
        else:
            bunit = i['tenant']['name']

        owner = i['tenant']
        if not owner:
            print 'Placeholder Owner'
        else:
            owner = i['tenant']['name']

        filewriter.writerow([bunit, owner])

...
```

Comment: This throws an error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`, and after converting it to int still throws the same error

Comment: Provide data example

Answer (score 0):

To open() function, you need to provide a filename as parameter.
Here you are providing an already open file as a parameter. Hence, first error.

The csvfile is already open and you do not need to open it again to write to it.

To write to the file, you can store the data in a list and then write to file at end of function.

Suppose I want to write r1c1,r1c2,r2c1,r2c2,r3c1,r3c2 in cells-A1,B1,A2,B2,A3,B3 respectively, then I would do something like the following:-

```
listtowrite = [['r1c1','r1c2'],['r2c1','r2c2'],['r3c1','r3c2']]

csvfile = open('my_file.csv', 'w')
for arow in listtowrite:
    for acolumn in arow:
        csvfile.write(acolumn+',')
    csvfile.write('\n')
csvfile.close()
```